# Flutter custom onTap scale effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to create custom `onTap` (or any on other `onTap` callbacks provided by `GestureDetector` "indicator" where content(child) is scaled-down and text becomes darker, like to this:[image: example]

Is there already a prebuilt package for that type of animation? If not can you at least fix snippet below.

I tried creating one using `AnimationController`, `Transform.scale` and various combinations of `onTap` callbacks but it's pretty unresponsive (gets 'stuck' all the time)

Here is a basic snippet:

```
 double squareScaleA = 1;
  AnimationController _controllerA;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controllerA = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        lowerBound: 0.9,
        upperBound: 1.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    _controllerA.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        squareScaleA = _controllerA.value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (dp) {
        _controllerA.forward();
      },
      onTapUp: (dp) {
        _controllerA.reverse();
      },
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: squareScaleA,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue with my code, the animation was "reversed", on onTapDown would cause `child` to expand (nothing happened since `child` was already at max scale), so I just reversed `_controllerA.reverse` and `_controllerA.forward` (actually replaced  `_controllerA.forward` with `_controllerA.fling`).
This is final code:

```
class OnTapScaleAndFade extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final void Function() onTap;
  const OnTapScaleAndFade({Key key, this.child, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnTapScaleAndFadeState createState() => _OnTapScaleAndFadeState();
}

class _OnTapScaleAndFadeState extends State<OnTapScaleAndFade>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  double squareScaleA = 1;
  AnimationController _controllerA;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controllerA = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      lowerBound: 0.98,
      upperBound: 1.0,
      value: 1,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10),
    );
    _controllerA.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        squareScaleA = _controllerA.value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: () {
        _controllerA.reverse();
        widget.onTap();
      },
      onTapDown: (dp) {
        _controllerA.reverse();
      },
      onTapUp: (dp) {
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
          _controllerA.fling();
        });
      },
      onTapCancel: () {
        _controllerA.fling();
      },
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: squareScaleA,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerA.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Feel free to add your custom gesture callbacks, I needed only onTap.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zoom_tap_animation: ^1.1.0`

It handles what you need.

**Usage:**

default use of ZoomTapAnimation widget

```
ZoomTapAnimation(
      onTap: (){},
      child: YOUR_WIDGET
);
```

and you can also define custom parameters

```
ZoomTapAnimation(
      child: YOUR_WIDGET,
      onTap: (){},
      onLongTap: (){},
      enableLongTapRepeatEvent: false,
      longTapRepeatDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 0.93,
      beginDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 20),
      endDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 120),
      beginCurve: Curves.decelerate,
      endCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
);
```

more info here: https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_tap_animation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pub pack. You can change the animation as you wish. With scaleCoefficient you can adjust the speed. If you wrap the So widget with it, it will look animated

https://pub.dev/packages/spring_button
Example;

```
SpringButton(
          SpringButtonType.OnlyScale,
          row(
            "Increment",
            Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onTapDown: (_) => incrementCounter(),
          onLongPress: () => timer = Timer.periodic(
            const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            (_) => incrementCounter(),
          ),
          onLongPressEnd: (_) {
            timer?.cancel();
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but given package doesn't seem to work, my child widget won't animate